# How to adjust the position of image while drop

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, drag-and-drop

How to adjust the drop position of image while drag and drop into the droppable div..? 
When trying to drop the image into workspace(droppable) div, the image not accurately 
drop in the position where it is dropped.
Below is the code i used to adjust left and right position of image while drop.

```
leftAdjust = Math.abs(obj.position().left) - Math.abs($(window).width()-(workspace.offset().left + workspace.outerWidth()));
topAdjust = obj.position().top - workspace.offset().top;
```

I have a working example code [link](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/8zp9kfpj/3/) which works perfect where drag the images from left side to the workspace.
The image gets x and y position from its workspace div after dropped(it also works fine).

But i can't able to achieve the same drop with accurate position functionality when the images are right side to the workspace.
This is the code [link](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/8zp9kfpj/4/) need to solve.

P.S: Please run the codes in jsfiddle by resizing with maximum screen to analyze the working progress.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Drag-and-Drop-images-from-one-DIV-to-another-using-jQuery.aspx

use this link and view demo its more better than this ....................

Comment: I need to drop the image in accurate position where dropped on the workspace(droppable) div. In your example all dropped images gets dropped one by one adjacent to each images. So how i can use your give demo code.. If i am not correct means., please suggest any other solution..

Comment: Okay okay I understood  I am trying to do this